# Wwriting links to database in a foreach loop fails

Tags: php, mysql

I am using [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to write records to a database, however it doesn't seem to write the records.

The problem is with the foreach loop. It outputs all the urls and the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: url in C:\xampp\htdocs\meh\crawler.php on line 28

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","spidermankillssuperman","expatriates");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$links = array (
    'http://www.expatriates.com/classifieds/bhr/hs/index100.html'

);
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $html = file_get_html($link);

    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
        if(strpos($element->href, "cls"))
            $url = "http://expatriates.com".$element->href . '<br>';

        echo $url;
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO urlstocrawl (url)
    VALUES ('$url')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo '<br>'.'<p>'."1 record added";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Have you considered the very faint possibility that the content of a web page might conceivably contain quote characters?

Comment: Plus, I think your brace for `foreach ($links as $link) {` may be misplaced.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: url in C:\xampp\htdocs\meh\crawler.php on line 28

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, it outputs all the urls I want, I am just having a hard time inserting them into the database.

Comment: I have never seen/used `file_get_html()`. and php reference seems to have a hard time finding it also... http://ca1.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=file_get_html unless that's some custom function? can we see it?

Comment: Felix: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: have your table `urlstocrawl` only one datafield ?

Comment: I can insert other records and variables into the database, I just cannot insert the results from the foreach loop.

Comment: moskito-x, It has 4, id, url, crawled, lastcrawled

Comment: try `$sql="INSERT INTO urlstocrawl VALUES('$url')";` if you really have only one datafield !!!

Comment: Doing proper indentation would help you a lot reading your own code. Clearly `$url` is not defined, as you're told, unless `$element->href` contains "cls"—but you're still trying to use it in your DB expression.

Comment: so you have to insert all fields `VALUES(NULL,'$url','','');`

Comment: I am using Simple Html Dom to get all the anchors, then I am filtering through the urls to get all the urls that contain "cls".

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Do a `var_dump($sql);` to see what you've got going through, IF anything is going through, as it's already been stated by Ronni. What does `echo $url;` reveal?

Comment: @moskito-x no. fields not defined will be filled by mysql with default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want your mysql query to insert *foreach* link in you html file, not run *once* after the loop. move the code inside the loop:

```
foreach ( $html->find('a') as $element ) {
    if ( strpos($element->href, "cls") !== false ) {
        $url = "http://expatriates.com" . $element->href . '<br>';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO urlstocrawl (url) VALUES ('$url')";
        if ( !mysqli_query($con,$sql) ) {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo '<br>'.'<p>'."1 record added" . $url;
    }
}
```

Note the modification to the `if` condition. [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) returns either `false` when the string is absent or an integer indicating the position, **starting at 0**. This means the condition could fail if `cls` is at the start of the string. With this strict type checking you can be sure of the desired behavior.

Comment: @Fred-ii- mille gratie

Comment: Prego amico mio, ciao é buongiorno!